# Why variables inside a function don't get searched in provided global namespace when using timeit or exec function?

Tags: python, exec, timeit

As a minimal example, I want to timeit `fn` function which has a `x` variable inside. So I passed `{'x': 20, 'fn': fn}` as my global namespace:

```
from timeit import timeit

def fn():
    print('This line executed.')
    return x

print(timeit('fn()', globals={'x': 20, 'fn': fn}, number=1_000_000))
```

I thought that because `x` is not local, Python checks the global namespace to find it. Then I get back `"This line executed."` followed by a NameError which says : `name 'x' is not defined`. But Python sees `{'x': 20, 'fn': fn}` namespace because when I remove the `'fn': fn` part, the error changes to `name 'fn' is not defined`.

Same is true for `exec` function(If that helps or has a relationship):

```
def fn():
    print('This line executed.')
    return x

s = """def fn():
    print('This line executed.')
    return x"""

exec('fn()', {'x': 10, 'fn': fn})
```

How can I introduce `x` to these functions? Is it The only option to define them as module-level variables and pass `globals()` dictionary to `global` argument?

Comment: I don't understand how an answer here would enable you to *solve a practical problem*; but I reproduced the issue (it also applies to `eval`) and I agree it's interesting and I don't have a ready answer.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel tbh, passing `globals()` is enough... I was doing some performance checks on local and global variables look-up, then I found I'm unable to do this. Also I was unable to pass at least a local namespace to introduce `x` to these functions and force python to find them in local namespace(`exec` accepts local namespace), again failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As document says about [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

> Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. This
> is always the dictionary of the current module (**inside a function or
> method, this is the module where it is "defined", not the module from
> which it is called**).

This specifically addressed my issue. So when when Python tries to find `x` inside `fn` function, (because it's not local or non-local) it will go and find where it is defind and look at global namespace *which the function is defined in*, not the global dictionary we provide as a global namespace.

Although `{'x': 20, 'fn': fn}` is the global dictionary which Python can find the label `fn`, but the `fn` function itself is not defined there, it is only *called* there.

Answer (score 2):

Each module has it's own global variables,
when we say `'fn': fn` we mean:

- use `fn` in it's own module (e.g. `answer.py`) which has it's own global variables.

So if there is no global variable like `x` in `answer.py`, `fn` cannot call it and you will get `NameError`.

Here is an example:

```
# content of answer.py

x = 10


def k1():
    print(f'{globals()["x"]}')


s = """
print(globals()['x'])
"""

# uses current's module ('answer.py') global variables to run script in `s`
exec(s)

# creates new global variables to run script in `s`
exec(s, {'x': 20})

# uses current's module global variables to call `k1` in module 'answer.py' which has his own global variables
exec('k1()')

# creates new global variables to call `k1` in module 'answer.py' which has his own global variables
# when we say 'k1': k1, it means use `k1` in module 'answer.py' which has his own global variables
exec('k1()', {'k1': k1, 'x': 20})
```

results:

```
10
20
10
10
```

so if you want to tell those functions to use your `x` in your global variables you have some options such as:

- change the global variables of that module
- don't use a module function and write it in a string and pass your global variables to it

Comment: Great+, I found that this behavior is indeed documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals), I've included that in my answer as well.